# timetable with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I've a jQuery timetable for allotting timeslots for the week days. My script for weekdays is,

```
<table class="container" id="tabTimetable">
            <tr class="timtebleheader">
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="monday">
                <td class="timetableweekday">Monday</td>
            </tr>
            <tr  class="tuesday">
                <td class="timetableweekday">Tuesday</td>
            </tr>
            ...... upto saturday
            ......
</table>
```

by using another div am allotting the timing like 08:00 - 09:00, 09:00 - 10:00, 10:00 - 11:00 like this, so my table is now divided with three columns with the timings as column headings. and am allotting the timings into the table as

```
var totalCol += 1;
$("#tabTimetable > tbody > tr:gt(0)").append("<td class='timetableslot " + totalCol + "' onclick='selTimeSlot(this);'></td>");
```

and now my table is like this,

[image]

and am gettin the current row and column as,

```
function selTimeSlot(objCol) {

        var pos   = $(objCol).position();           

        currentCol = $(objCol).parent().children().index($(objCol));
        currentRow = $(objCol).parent().parent().children().index($(objCol).parent());
```

if I click particular cell here, a window with a textbox to search staff appear, and in the autocomplete selected item of staff, am binding the details into that particular cell like

```
 select: function (event, ui) {

                var timetableItem = new Object();

                timetableItem.StaffId   = ui.item.id;
                timetableItem.Name      = ui.item.value;
                timetableItem.Photo     = ui.item.image;
                timetableItem.ItemName  = $("#txtItemName").val();
                timetableItem.Row       = currentRow;
                timetableItem.Col       = currentCol;
                timetableItem.From      = slots[currentCol - 1].From;
                timetableItem.To        = slots[currentCol - 1].To;
                timetableItem.WeekDay   = currentRow;
                timetableItem.SectionId = selsection;

                timetable[timetable.length] = timetableItem;

                $("#selItem").hide();
                updateTable();
```

and my updateTable function is,
    function updateTable() {

```
        for (var i = 0; i < timetable.length; i++) {              

            if (timetable[i] != null) {
                var row = $("#tabTimetable > tbody > tr").eq(timetable[i].Row);
                var col = $(row).find("td:eq(" + timetable[i].Col + ")");

                var data = "<div class='timetableslotselected'><table width='100%'><tr><td align='right'><div class='close16' onclick='removeItem(" + timetable[i].Row + "," + timetable[i].Col + ",event)' /></td></tr></table><div><table><tr><td><img src='" + timetable[i].Photo + "' width='32px' height='32px'/></td><td>" + timetable[i].Name + " ( " + timetable[i].ItemName + " )</td></tr></table></div></div> ";


                $(col).html(data);
            }
```

here when I try to allot particular data in different rows(1 data in each row) the data is allotted to the particular cell, no problem here, but when I try to allot more than one data in the same column all the datas are appended to the same cell, how to fix this issue can anyone help me here......

its coming like this

[image]

Comment: Look at jQuery's .data() functionality.

Comment: data returns correct value, the problem is appending the data into a particular cell...

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a question of structuring the table in HTML, so it might help if you checked my solution to a similar layout problem:

[setting hidden overflow on a table within a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027174/setting-hidden-overflow-on-a-table-within-a-table/10027573#10027573)

It's a fairly simple solution that makes a scrollable div take up a given width and allows it to span several time slots.

http://jsfiddle.net/aramk/wHEm6/3/

This will allow you to add several one-line events into the scrollable slot without having the table expand.